# as2 get current frame of dynamic clip

Tags: actionscript-2

I'm trying to determine what frame number (_currentframe) a dynamic clip is currently at.

Here, I set the name of the clip in the library-

```
_root.clipName="rabbit";
```

The "_root.clipName" needs to be variable because it changes.

Here, I attach it to the stage- (works, linked library clip "rabbit" attaches to stage)

```
        Object(_root).attachMovie("myClip",_root.clipName,_root.getNextHighestDepth(),    {_x:200), _y:200)});
```

Then, I want to store that frame number to use in a different function -

```
_root.myFrame=_root.clipName._currentframe; <- (doesn't work)
```

Using the below trace methods, none seem to return the frame number-

```
trace(_root.clipName._currentframe);     - returns undefined 
trace(_root.clipName[_currentframe]);    - returns undefined 
trace(_root.clipName._currentframe);     - returns undefined 
trace(_root['clipName']._currentframe);  - returns undefined
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*myClip* is the `linkage name` of your MovieClip in the library, and *Rabbit* its `instance name`:

```
this.attachMovie("myClip", "Rabbit", this.getNextHighestDepth());

var myFrame:Number;

Rabbit.onEnterFrame = function():Void {
    myFrame = this._currentframe;
}
```

So you directly test your instance's enterFrame, and your `global variable` *myframe* is accessible from everywhere.

**With your clipName variable**

You can call your *clipName* variable instead of *Rabbit*. I've renamed it *myInstance*:

```
this.attachMovie("myClip", "Rabbit", this.getNextHighestDepth());

var myFrame:Number;
var myInstance:MovieClip = Rabbit;

myInstance.onEnterFrame = function():Void {
    myFrame = this._currentframe;
}
```